# AS3 Object Name & Value

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, object

i am trying to return the Value of the Objects name, any help would be a huge help! thank you.

```
var o:Object = new Object();
var n:String = "NAME"
o[n] = "DATA";

for each (var p in o){
trace("name="+o[p]+" data="+p);
}
```

outputs - 
name=undefined data=DATA

where it should be outputting - 
name=NAME data=DATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For looping thru Object properties, drop the "each":

```
var o:Object = new Object();
var n:String = "NAME"
o[n] = "DATA";

for (var p in o)
{
    trace("name="+o[p]+" data="+p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use a regular for loop vs a "for each" loop http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-loops/

Comment: how do you loop through and Object with a regular loop?